# How to create an ARGB_8888 pixel value?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, pixel

Say I want to create an array of pixel values to pass into the `createBitmap` method described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config%29). I have three int values `r, g, b` in the range 0 - 0xff. How do I transform those into an opaque pixel `p`?

Does the alpha channel go in the high byte or the low byte?

I googled up the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html) but it only states that:

> Each pixel is stored on 4 bytes. Each channel (RGB and alpha for
>   translucency) is stored with 8 bits of precision (256 possible
>   values.) This configuration is very flexible and offers the best
>   quality. It should be used whenever possible.

So, how to write this method?

```
int createPixel(int r, int g, int b)
{
  return ?
}
```

Comment: docs are updated and now contain sample of code, but it is wrong. OMG Google. Graham Borland answer is right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html):

```
(alpha << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue
```

Answer (score 11):

It looks like the [RGBA pixel format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space) is pretty well documented and I'm assuming that's what the Android docs mean, just using a different name to match the channel membership position in the bit field:

[image]

Something like this should work:

```
int createPixel(int r, int g, int b) {
  return createPixel(r, g, b, 0xff);
}

int createPixel(int r, int g, int b, int a) {
  return (a<<24) | (r<<16) | (g<<8) | b;
}
```

Also, you might want to use a `byte` instead of an `int` to avoid overflow-type errors, or mask only the bits you want:

```
int createPixel(int r, int g, int b, int a) {
  return ((a & 0xff) << 24)
       | ((r & 0xff) << 16)
       | ((g & 0xff) << 8)
       | ((b & 0xff));
}
```

Although clamping the values to `[0,255]` might make more sense.

Comment: Alright, this is called *RGBA* and in android its called *ARGB*? Could you formulate your answer as a return statement with apropriate shifts and adds/ors in the method above?

Comment: @vidstige: hmm, yeah, the docs are pretty vague.  I am indeed assuming that Android's *ARGB_8888* is the standard *RGBA* pixel format renamed to match the channel membership position in the bit field.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your arguments should be bytes, not ints, but I guess this could be an implementation issue.

In general you would do something like

```
return b | r<<8 | g<<16 | 255<<24;
```

assuming your alpha is 255 (non-transparent).

Comment: Thanks. yeah, I just wanted to avoid all the confusion with bytes beeing signed and all.

Comment: True. Just make sure they're 8-bit ints by content.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
int createPixel(int r, int g, int b)
{
    return 0xff000000 | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
}
```

or, if you want to be baroque:

```
int createPixel(int r, int g, int b)
{
    return (((((-1 << 8) | r) << 8) | g) << 8) | b;
}
```